# What should I look at to diagnose an SSAS dimension definition error?

Tags: ssas, dimensions

I'm pretty new to SSAS and am having problems presenting aggregations based on two different dates.  Here is a quick rundown:

fact table:
  sale measure
  order date
  ship date

time dimension
  pk_date
  fiscal year aggregation columns

I have defined in the data source view two different relationships from the fact table to the time dimension table, one joining pk_date to order date, and the other pk_date to ship date.

I've defined two different dimensions, ship_hier and order_hier, which use the two different relations.

SSAS doesn't seem to want to display data based on ship date.  Both of the dimensions aggregta the data on order_date, even though the ship dimension is clearly defined to use the ship date rlationship.

At this point I have no idea where to even look.  I'm sure it's something elemental.  What should I look at to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem might be because of you have added date fields for measures with some aggregation function probably `SUM`. You shouldn't select date fields for measures of the cube or check that there is no aggregation function for them.

Comment: By "added date fields for measures" do you mean "used a date field as a measure"?  If so, that's not the case.  All measures are numeric.  There are date fields that are used to join to the time dimension, but they are not measures, they are dimension keys.